# Call Custom Dialog in Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

In Navigation drawer i call Fragment class after that In Fragment Class when i want to create custom dialog then getting error

```
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply
 a layout_height attribute. 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):
    at
 android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5457)
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5592)
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:610)
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:554)
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:56)
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:477) 04-14
 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):  at
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 04-14
 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):  at
 com.dwellesque.MyProfile.onCreateView(MyProfile.java:54) 04-14
 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):  at
 android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635) 04-14
 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):  at
 android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426) 04-14
 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):  at
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 04-14
 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):  at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 04-14
 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):  at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-14 11:20:46.974:
 E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 04-14
 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):  at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-14
 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):  at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-14 11:20:46.974:
 E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 04-14
 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):  at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my java code is where i call custom dialog

```
public class MyProfile extends Fragment {

Button btnSave,btnChange;
EditText txtFname;
EditText txtLane;
EditText txtEmil;
EditText txtCity;
EditText txtState;
EditText txtZip;
String strFname,strLname,strEmail,strCity,strState,strZip;
Document doc;
ArrayList<String> mylist= new ArrayList<String>();
SharedPreferences preferences = null;
String prefusername,prefemail,prefpass;
/*ArrayList<String> arFname= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arLname= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arEmail= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arCity= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arState= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arZip= new ArrayList<String>(); */
public MyProfile(){

}

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myprofile, container, false);

     preferences=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Login", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
     prefusername=preferences.getString("USERNAME", "DEFAULT");
     prefemail=preferences.getString("EMAIL", "DEFAULT");
     prefpass= preferences.getString("PASSWORD", "DEFAULT");
     txtFname= (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_Profile_Fname);
     txtLane =(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_Profile_Lname);
     txtEmil= (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_Profile_email);
     txtCity= (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_Profile_City);
     txtState= (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.State_spinner);
     txtZip = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_Profile_Zip);
      btnChange = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_Profile_PASSWORD);

      strFname= getEditText(txtFname);
      strLname= getEditText(txtLane);
      strCity= getEditText(txtCity);
      strState=  getEditText(txtState);
      strEmail= getEditText(txtEmil);
      strZip= getEditText(txtZip);

      btnChange.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            changePass();
        }
    });



     return rootView;
 }



 void changePass()
 {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.change_password);
        dialog.setTitle("Change password");
        final EditText txtPassword = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.changepwd);
        final EditText txtVpassword = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.changevpwd);
        Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnch_ok);
        Button btnCancle = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnch_cancle);


 }
 }
```

Dialog change_password xml code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/changepwd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true"
        android:hint="Password" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/changevpwd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Verify Password"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <LinearLayout 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_Verify"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_centerInParent="true">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnch_ok"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:text="Ok" >
            </Button>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnch_cancle"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/check_Pwd"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:text="Cancel" >
                </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**myprofile Layout is here**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/myprofilelayout"
android:background="@drawable/bg">


<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" 
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_Profile">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        >
            <!-- First Name -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/txt_profile_Fname"
                android:text="First Name"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#4a596e"
                android:textSize="14dip" 
                android:layout_weight="0.5"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:inputType="textCapWords"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/edit_Profile_Fname"
                 android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:singleLine="true" 
                android:layout_weight="0.25"></EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >
            <!--Last Name -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_profile_Lname"
                android:text="Last Name" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#4a596e"
                android:textSize="14dip" android:layout_weight="0.5"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                 android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/edit_Profile_Lname"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"></EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"  >
            <!--Last Name -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_profile_email"
                android:text="Email" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#4a596e"
                android:textSize="14dip" android:layout_weight="0.5"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
               android:inputType="textCapWords"
                 android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/edit_Profile_email"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"></EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >
            <!-- City -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_profile_City"
                android:text="City" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="14dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/keyword1"
                android:textColor="#4a596e"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                 android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/edit_Profile_City"
                android:singleLine="true" android:layout_weight="0.25"></EditText>
        </LinearLayout>










        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >
            <!-- Zip -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_profile_Zip1"
                android:textColor="#4a596e"
            android:text="State"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="14dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/State_spinner"
               android:layout_weight="0.25"
                 android:singleLine="true"></EditText>
        </LinearLayout>





        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"  >
            <!-- Zip -->
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_profile_Zip"
                android:textColor="#4a596e"
                android:text="ZIP" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="14dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"></TextView>
            <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/edit_Profile_Zip"
                 android:layout_weight="0.25"
                 android:singleLine="true"></EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <!-- Password -->

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_Profile_PASSWORD"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
           android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Change Password" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>



        <Button android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
             android:background="@drawable/rounded"
             android:text="Save"
              android:textSize="18sp"
            android:id="@+id/profile_save"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**My activity_main xml file is here**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView

        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#200000"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please Help Me how i can call custom Dialog in This class

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: show `myprofile` layout

Comment: i have updated question please see change_password xml and thanks for replay

Comment: Which is your line number 17 ?

Comment: @shayan pourvatan i upload myprofile layout please see

Comment: @Kuldeep post `activity_main.xml` That is where the problem is

Comment: @Raghunandan  I posted activity_main.xml file please see and thanks for replay

Comment: @Kuldeep that seems alright

Comment: @Raghunandan but where is error i could not find please suggest me How i can fix this error this error is occur  in Each Fragment activity I wasted my 3 days for this error

Comment: @Kuldeep the stacktrace indicates `android:layout_height` missing for `FrameLayout`. Try clean and build your xml looks fine

Comment: @Raghunandan i clean many time but not solve my problem

Comment: @Kuldeep i really can't see the problem

Comment: @Kuldeep one thing i can tell you your layout is messy. `android:layout_below="@+id/keyword1"` is not for linearlayout

Comment: @Kuldeep have you checked if my answer works for you?

Comment: @ubuntudroid did you even check the stacktrace. `java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply
 a layout_height attribute.`

Comment: @Raghunandan No need to get offensive - of course I did. And I also read Kuldeep's note about the problem occuring when trying to create a dialog. Checking the dialog's XML isn't too far off imho...

Comment: @ubuntudroid but the stacktrace says differently. either op has not posted the right one or there is something else wrong. Also the layout is very messy. op has used attributes of `RelativeLayout` in `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

From your error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply
 a layout_height attribute. 04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)` it shows that in your layout one of your view is missing the attribute of `layout_height`.

Add just `layout_height` attribute in the view in which its missing.

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Thanks for Replay but i add  >>layout_height in every view

Answer (score 0):

```
04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5592) 
04-14 11:20:46.974: E/AndroidRuntime(5245):    at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:610)
```

I am guessing in `activity_main.xml` you have a `FrameLayout` which is a `ViewGroup` for which `android:layout_height` attribute is mising.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what you're doing in your `change_password.xml` layout is defining the a `wrap_content` height for the root `RelativeLayout` and `fill_parent` height for the child `LinearLayout` with id `text`. Now, if you were the layout interpreter, how would you resolve this circular layout dependency problem? ;) Make the `LinearLayout`'s height fixed or `wrap_content` and everything should work as intended.

Comment: Did you also try to set a fixed hight?